# Lock screen with kernel level driver on windows

Tags: driver, windows-kernel

Is there any way to lock a windows workstation, using a kernel level driver?

I need to do it in kernel, in order to achieve most possible protection and avoid bypassing.

ThnX

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you *think* that doing this in the kernel is better, but really, your best bet is to simply call the function designed to do this from usermode: [`LockWorkStation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875(v=vs.85).aspx).

What attack vector do you envision that running in the kernel will protect you against?